# Storing and mapping/searching binary vectors?

Tags: database, postgresql, vector, redis, binary

I want to store ~1000 .. ~mln binary vectors of size ~100000 .. ~1mln bits.
The search is based on binary operations, overlap-bits count, hamming distance, ...etc.

Something like :

```
SELECT id,vec FROM abc ORDER BY count(param & vec) LIMIT TOP 5%

SELECT id,vec FROM abc ORDER BY overlap(param,vec) LIMIT TOP 5%

SELECT vec FROM abc WHERE vec = param
```

It doesnt have to be SQL, this is just for illustration..

What is best DB,files,cache ... which one ?

Current best idea is using indexed-binary vectors and storing them as arrays in postgresql  DB. The vectors are sparse, so it should work

Comment: how do you Redis in your solution?

Comment: in Redis you can search only linear